# help with $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} {\ln(xy + 1) \over x}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Compute:

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ if $f(x,\ y)={\ln(xy + 1) \over x}$

According to Wolfram the limit is 0.

I'm trying to verify it by approaching the origin from different paths.

When approaching the origin from $x$:

$\lim_{(x,y=0) \to (0)} f(x,0) = {\ln(1) \over x}={0\over x}= 0$

However, I don't know how to proceed when approaching the origin from $y$. In this case, $x=0$ and the denominator is zero.

$\lim_{(x=0,y) \to (0)} f(0,y) = {\ln(1) \over 0}={0\over 0}$

I guess I should try get rid of that zero in the denominator, but I don't see how as if I set $x=0$ all the variables disappear.

Comment: Alpha (along with some people) doesn't worry about removable singularities.

Answer (score 4):

We have $\ln(1+x)\sim_0 x$ hence we find
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}{\ln(xy + 1) \over x}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{xy}{x}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}y=0$$

Answer (score 3):

The expression 
$${\log(1+xy)\over x}$$
is not defined in a full neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Therefore the limit doesn't make sense without further comment. One way out could be the following: The function
$$g(z):=\cases{{\log(1+z)\over z}\quad&$(z\ne 0)$ \cr 1&$(z=0)$\cr}$$
is analytic in a neighborhood of $z=0$ and has a Taylor expansion $g(z)=1-{z\over2}+{z^2\over3}-\ldots$ at $0$. More important, we have
$$\log(1+z)= z\>g(z)\qquad\bigl(|z|<1\bigr)\ .$$
It follows that for $|x|<1$, $\>|y|<1$ we can write
$$\log(1+xy)=xy\>g(xy)$$
and therefore
$${\log(1+xy)\over x}=y\> g(xy)\qquad(x\ne0)\ .$$
As the right side of the last equation is continuous in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ the expression in question can be extended continuously into this full neighborhood, and the limit when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ is obviously $=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information, the function $f(x,y)$ is not defined on the line $x = 0$. Of course, we can try to define:

$$f(0,y) := \lim_{x \to 0} f(x,y)$$

which by an application of De l'Hôpital's rule amounts to:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(xy+1)}x= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac y{xy+1}}1 = y$$

This shows that $f$ may be continuously extended to the line $x=0$ by setting $f(0,y) = y$. It follows at once that the limit $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$, if it is to exist, must equal the iterated limit:

$$\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,y) = \lim_{y\to0} y = 0$$

One can subsequently set out to prove that this is indeed the sought limit, e.g. using the approach of Sami Ben Romdhane, using suitable theorems about limits, or via $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ methods.

Answer (score 1):

Using a little Taylor series:

$$\log(1+xy)=xy-\frac{x^2y^2}2+\mathcal O(x^3y^3)\implies$$

$$\frac{\log(1+xy)}x=y-\frac{xy^2}2+\mathcal O(x^2y^3)\xrightarrow[ (x,y,)\to (0,0)]{}0$$

Comment: this is a one dimensional Taylor expansion.